# health checks: targets showing unhealthy, tasks showing healthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to set up a Flask-based API service as a Docker image. The python script handles a `/healthcheck` route by returning an HTTP 200 response. I uploaded the container to ECR and created a task definition for that container. I created the healthcheck for that definition as `CMD-SHELL,curl -f http://localhost:5000/healthcheck || exit 1`. The service that uses that definition shows that out of the two targets, both are unhealthy. However, when I look at the two tasks for the cluster, both tasks are healthy.

I've tried going into the Target Group and looking at the health check - even if I set it there to use `/healthcheck` as the path, and explicitly set the port to `5000`, I'm getting "Request timed out" as the status detail. I opened up port 5000 to just my IP address in the security group and I can confirm that hitting the external IPs for each target individually on port 5000 and the healthcheck URL results in the expected 200 response.

Is there something immediately obvious that I'm missing? Is there a way to get terminal access to the individual targets so I can play around and see if there are any relevant logs?

Comment: The target group health checks are unrelated to the `CMD-SHELL` docker health checks. If The target group health checks are failing with request timed out, then the most likely reason is the security group assigned to the task isn't allowing the health check requests. Please show your security group settings. Also are you using an ALB, or an NLB?

For terminal access: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html

Comment: "the most likely reason is the security group assigned to the task isn't allowing the health check requests." This was it - I went into the security group and created a new inbound rule with the custom source of the ALB's security group on the port exposed by the container, and the targets all deployed as healthy. Thanks!